# XPages: create current Datetime in ssjs and save to a Datetime Notes form field

Tags: datetime, xpages, lotus-notes, lotus-domino, xpages-ssjs

The only way i have found to store date in a Datetime field in a notes form is this:

```
theDoc2.replaceItemValue("lastAccess",session.createDateTime("Today"));
```

But this only creates a Date, not DateTime. Also, i dont want to create a static time like "Today 12" but i want the current datetime dynamicly.

Using this i get an error (Exception occurred calling method NotesDocument.replaceItemValue(string, Date) null):

```
theDoc2.replaceItemValue("lastAccess",@Now());
```

and using this, the form field changes from Date/Time to Text data type and i want to keep Date/Time type:

```
theDoc2.replaceItemValue("lastAccess",@Now().toLocaleString);
```

Any ideas?

Comment: When I use doc.replaceItemValue("dateField",session.createDateTime("Today")); I get a date field stored with both date and time. Have you checked the document properties to verify that your field does contain both date and time?

Comment: It is Date/Time List in document properties. The field is set to display both date and time but still with "Today" it only saves the date.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just gave it a try:

as you wrote, `.replaceItemValue("fieldName", @Now())` throws an error.

However, I got it to work with

```
.replaceItemValue("fieldName", session.createDateTime(@Now()))
```

In that case the value is stored in the Notes field as Time/Date with all necessary components as in

```
17.01.2014 12:45:51 CET
```

From what I can see, difference between the two is that @Now() returns a Date *data type*, whereas session.createDateTime() returns a *NotesDateTime object*

On the other hand, for me it's also working with your original method:

```
session.createDateTime("Today")
```

Don't know what's causing the prob on your side; do you have an editable represantion of the field on you xpage? If so, does it have some kind of converter enabled which could do some filtering during submit?

Answer (score 1):

i will answer my own question as i found a way. Please comment if you think it is not correct or best practice...

```
theDoc2.replaceItemValue("lastAccess",session.createDateTime("Today"+@Now().toLocaleTimeString()));
```

Answer (score 0):

A little late, but I had the same problem, but this method resolved it:

```
        DateTime datumtijd = session.createDateTime("Today");

        datumtijd.setNow(); //!!!!!!

        System.out.println((datumtijd).toString());
```

Hope it helps :)